# Is there a way to get the page name, for resource pages, in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-6

I am doing a sort of permission feature with groups where each group has different permission to access the ActiveAdmin pages. But some pages do not have the same name as their model...

```
ActiveAdmin.register Member, as: 'Customer' do # rubocop:disable Metrics/BlockLength
  actions :all, except: %w[new create destroy]
  filter :email
end
```

And in my Authorization Adapter I am trying to achieve something like:

```
class AdminAuthorization < ActiveAdmin::AuthorizationAdapter
  def authorized?(action, subject = nil)
    
    # This one is really a page, not linked to model.
    return true if subject.name == 'Dashboard'
    
    # this will be done more dynamically later with tables
    return false if subject.name == 'Customer' && !current_user.admin? 
  end
end
```

The "name" method works with Pages, but not with Resources. Is there a similar way to get the 'Customer' instead of 'Member' here? And how do I know if the resource is a Page or a Resource indeed?

Answer (score 0):

I used `bundle info activeadmin` to locate the gem source on my machine, and reading the source of  `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5@sfp-rails-6/gems/activeadmin-2.13.1/lib/active_admin/authorization_adapter` I noticed an `attr_reader` for `resource`.

Then I dropped a `byebug` at entry of authorized

```
def authorized?(action, subject = nil)
  byebug
  # ...
end
```

and dumped the `methods` this resource has (after requesting a custom active admin page) using `pp resource.methods` This gave a huge array with lots of methods, but I saw a lot of `resource_` methods, so I grepped these:

```
resource.methods.select{|m|m=~/resource/}
```

yielding

```
[
  :find_resource,
  :resource_name_extension,
  :resource_columns,
  :resource_attributes,
  :resource_class,
  :resource_column_names,
  :resource_table_name,
  :resource_quoted_column_name,
  :resource_class_name,
  :resource_label,
  :resource_name,
  :plural_resource_label,
  :resources_configuration
]
```

You can use this clause:

```
class AdminAuthorization < ActiveAdmin::AuthorizationAdapter
  def authorized?(action, subject = nil)
    return true if resource.resource_name.name == 'Customer'
  end
end
```

There is also:

```
resource.resources_configuration
```

which I encourage you to inspect. I haven't found a general way to query a `resource` for being a `Page` or `ActiveRecord` model.